# Maven invalid target release: 13

Tags: java, maven, build, java-13

I'm using Maven in Eclipse and i want to run my project with Java13. Every time i build my project i get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project subscriptionsmanager: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 13 -> [Help 1]
```

I've configured my pom.xml file inside `<properties>` as follows:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
```

and Java13 as JRE from Eclipse from Eclipse "Java Build Path" section.

[image]

Is there any settings that I have not considered?

Comment: the `mvn` command uses `JAVA_HOME` or the `java` from your `PATH`, so check if those are correctly configured.

Comment: Furthermore, note that Java 13 is outdated. It is better to use Java 11 or Java 15.

Comment: @Lino Do you know how can i check my PATH in Eclipse ?

Comment: @pz7 the PATH is from your operating system (OS), so you have to check that somewhere in your settings.

Comment: consider updating your plugin from `maven-compiler-plugin:3.1` to `maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [naman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746118/naman) suggested, you'll need to explicitly configure your maven compiler plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>13</source>
                <target>13</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above post, you can also directly mention the release in configuration.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```